# Json data not populated to pie chart?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts, pie-chart

I m returning a josn data from my controller  and binding it to a pie chart...but in the end i dnt get any thing in my page..
can any one tell me where am i doing wrong...

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var chart;
        alert('1');
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
        chart: {
           renderTo: 'container',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    defaultSeriesType: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
           text:'Resource Reports'
         },
       plotOptions: {
           pie: {
               allowPointSelect: true,
               cursor: 'pointer',
               dataLabels: {
                   enabled: true,
                   color: '#000000',
                   connectorColor: '#000000',
                   formatter: function () {
                       //return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.percentage + ' %';
                   }
               }
           }
       },
        series: [{
           type: 'pie',
           name: 'Fruits',
           data:[]
        }]
     };

            $.getJSON('<%= Url.Action("GetData","JqueryCharts") %>', null, function (data) {
                alert('2');                    
                options.series = json;
                chart = new Highcharts.chart(options);                                  

            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

this is my controller

```
        public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        //int Param1;
        //Param1 = 1;
        //DataEntitiesModel data = new DataEntitiesModel();
        //var procedure=db.Database.SqlQuery<DataEntitiesModel>("ResourceReports @EmployeeID",new SqlParameter("@EmployeeID", Param1) );
        //var procedure = db.Database.SqlQuery<DataEntitiesModel>("Select * from EmployeeDetails");
        //var data = db.ProjectReports.ToList().Select( e => new
        //{
        //    Id = e.EmployeeID,
        //    Name = e.EmployeeName
        //});
        var EmployeeDetails = db.EmployeeDetails.ToList<EmployeeDetail>().Select(e => new
        {
            id=e.EmployeId,
            Name = e.EmployeeName
        });
        return Json(EmployeeDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Does the pie chart work if you hard code the output of .getJSON into the series?

Comment: Also, why do you have $(document).ready(function () { nested within $(function(){?  Seems kind of redundant.

Comment: @Michael_B i dnt see that ....yes pie chart is working when i hard code it

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851122/blank-page-highchart-in-using-jquery-to-call-json-arrary/11852873#11852873

Comment: Could explain the correlation between your JsonResult and options.series = json; ? JsonResult appearts to be returning a list of employee id and names, how can you assign it the options.series ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your json output is made of numbers and not strings. Db queries generally return string, you ll need to cast them into float/int before you cnvrt to json

Answer (score 0):

Maybe?

```
$.getJSON('<%= Url.Action("GetData","JqueryCharts") %>', null, function (data) { 
            options.series = [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Fruits',
                data:json
            }];
            chart = new Highcharts.chart(options);                                  

        });
```

Comment: Except...where is 'json' set? Maybe you need to use data instead of 'json'