# JSON, Codeigniter, Highcharts and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, codeigniter, highcharts

I'm using CI (+HMVC) for showing a Highcharts with an ajax event on a form.

My pb is to create valids Series for the chart. I have to create 6 series from mysql DB. My chart code is inpired by 
[blank page highchart in using jquery to call json arrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851122/blank-page-highchart-in-using-jquery-to-call-json-arrary).

My View
(`<?=$instance_graph?>` is everywhere because I want to be able to instance multiple charts)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit<?=$instance_graph?>').click(function() {
        $('#rendu_graph<?=$instance_graph?>').html('');
        var form_data = {
        from : $('#from[name=from<?=$instance_graph?>]').val(),
        to : $('#to[name=to<?=$instance_graph?>]').val(),
        parametre : $('#parametre[name=parametres<?=$instance_graph?>]').val(),
        ajax : '1'
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?= site_url('graph_meteo/ajax_graph'); ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            async : false,
            data: form_data,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data) {
            //alert(msg) ;
            //$('#rendu_graph<?=$instance_graph?>').html(msg);
            var chartSeriesData=[];
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
                var series_name = item.name;
                var series_data = item.data;     
                var series = {data: item.data,name:series_name};
                chartSeriesData.push(series);
            });
            console.log(chartSeriesData) ;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({ //Début du Highchar
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'rendu_graph<?=$instance_graph?>',
                type: 'spline'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Graph' 
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Title'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'

            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'param 1'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %d %b %H:%M', this.x) + ': ' + this.y + ' m';
                }
            },

            series: chartSeriesData


        })
```

The console.log of the series created :

```
[Object { data="[Date.UTC(2013,02,06,14,15),65.09375]",  name="Station 1"}, Object { data="[Date.UTC(2013,02,06,14,15),65.09375]",  name="Station 1"}, Object { data="[Date.UTC(2013,02,06,14,15),65.09375]",  name="Station 1"}, Object { data="[Date.UTC(2013,02,06,14,30),63.425]",  name="Station 1"}.
```

[image]

And of course I have one serie for each object with no plot:

[image]

edit :I'm looking for a way to have  a nice working graph with these data ( 1 lines) and I want my code working for many lines/series. My big pb is to start from Query result to chart series format. An example could be nice answer.

I hope you could help me before I became mad!

Comment: What are you looking for help with? You didn't ask a question

Comment: You see ! I begin to be mad ! I have had real question at the bottom of the first post.

Answer (score 0):

First problem with your setup is that the data for each series is a string with an array in it. Currently it looks like:

```
{ data: "[Date.UTC(2013,02,06,14,15),65.09375]",  name: "Station 1"}
```

The name looks ok, but the data should be a real javascript array, not a string. This is what you want it to look like:

```
{ data: [Date.UTC(2013,02,06,14,15),65.09375],  name: "Station 1"}
```

When that is solved I think you should put all data-points in the same series-definition. So instead of:

```
{ data: [Date.UTC(2013,02,06,14,15),65.09375],  name: "Station 1"},
{ data: [Date.UTC(2013,02,07,14,15),67.09375],  name: "Station 1"}
```

You should have one series with many points:

```
{ data: [
      [Date.UTC(2013,02,06,14,15),65.09375],
      [Date.UTC(2013,02,07,14,15),67.09375],
      <more data points here>],
  name="Station 1"},
```

Comment: I totally agree but I don't know how to collapse all points with one "name"

Comment: I don't think you should create separate series for each point in the first place, if you avoid that then there's no need to collapse them back. See the body of the `$.each(data, function(i,item){` in your code. You are push:ing a new series config for each point.

Comment: Okay, now I have something like this :[{"name":"1","data":"[(2013,02,07, 19,00,00), 75.73125],[(2013,02,07, 06,45,00), 92.83125],... But when I loop on these data with that $.each(data,function(key,value) {console.log(value) ;}); I have each number seperated by comma !